# Respond to /me in mIRC scripts

Tags: scripting, mirc

When creating mIRC scripts, how do I detect when someone uses /me and what he has said?

For example, if someone types "/me says hello" (which shows on screen something similar to "Name says hello"), how would I respond something like "Welcome!"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
on *:ACTION:Hello:#:{
    describe $chan Welcome!
}
```

Change "Hello" to anything you want (support wildcards), and "#" to the channel you want this to work on (using just # would make it to work on every channel).

Example to use of wildcard on ON ACTION event (Beware! would reply every /me action on any channel!):

```
on *:ACTION:*:#:{
    describe $chan Welcome!
}
```